# Radioactive isotopes differential equationa

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a hard time finding the correct differential equation to my problem. The problem is :

There's 2 isotopes: A and B. A is is transforming into B to a rate proportional to its quantity and B is decreasing to a rate proportional to its quantity.

I need to find an equation that gives the quantity of the B isotope at time t.

I've found the the equation of the lost of A over time, but I don't know how to integrate it to the differential equation of B.

The quantity of A isotope that has turned into B over time is y(t) = yi*e^(kt)

**edit**
B is not a fixed quantity. It's the lost quantity of A so the lost rate of B is proportional to the quantity B at the time which is equals to the lost quantity of A - minus the quantity of B that has been lost over time.

Thanks for the help

Comment: since $B$ is decreasing , does it transform into $A$ ?

Comment: No only A into B. B is just "vanishing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A(t)$ be the amount of substance A at time $t$, and let $B(t)$ be the amount of substance B at time $t$.

For suitable decay constants $a$ and $b$, we have
$$A'(t)=-aA(t),$$
and 
$$B'(t)=-A'(t)-bB(t)=aA(t)-bB(t).$$ 
The second equation comes from the fact that B atoms are "born" (through decay) at rate $aA(t)$, and die at rate $bB(t)$.

How we handle these is a matter of taste. If it is familiar, we can express the system in matrix notation. The more straightforward approach is to solve the first equation explicitly for $A(t)$, and substitute in the second equation. We obtain a fairly simple but non-homogeneous linear equation.

Comment: A(t) is the quantity of A or the lost quantity of A?

Comment: Yes. As usual I had a sign wrong though. Corrected!

Comment: Sorry, my answer was ambiguous. $A(t)$ is amount of substance A at time $t$, not amount lost. Similar for $B(t)$.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, is this taking into account the rate of B already lost over time when it evaluates its rate. What I am having trouble with is it always takes aA(t) the "total" quantity of A that has been lost though some of this quantity has already been lost? Not sure if I am making myself clear. Let's say at during the first 5min, A has lost 10 "qty". B will has gain these 10 "qty" but will have lost 1 so B quantity is now 9. Now at let's say 15min A will have lost a total of 13 "qty". When you evaluate B'(t) you don't consider the unit already lost during the first 5min.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the explaination. Great details.

Comment: We wrote down an equation for the *rate of change* of B. The integration (solving the DE) takes care of keeping track.

Comment: Ok nice. Thanks for the help